# images wont appear in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<h:outputLink value="javascript:void(0)" onclick="PF('dlg').show();" title="login">
        <p:graphicImage name="login.jpg" />
</h:outputLink>
```

even tried this:

<  p:graphicImage value="#{login.jpg}" />

as soon as I run the server, the broken image icon appears and it is clickable, even the prompt for login also appears but the image itself doesnt appear, tried png and jpg format as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the image in for example `Web Pages/resources/img/login.jpg` or `WebContent/resources/img/login.jpg` and reference it with either of these:

```
<p:graphicImage value="/resources/img/login.jpg" />
<p:graphicImage url="/resources/img/login.jpg" />
<p:graphicImage name="img/login.jpg" />
```